# Elements won't center horizontally within a jumbotron element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am using a jumbotron as a section on my page.

What I want to do is center the child-elements of the jumbotron both horizontally and vertically within the parent element.

I've tried multiple classes that we pointed on other SO posts, such as: span8 centering, jumbotron d-flex align-items-center, justify-content-center, etc.

This is my code:

```html
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="span8 centering">
      <h1>Text 1</h1>
      <p>Text 2</p>
      <br>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JC82Il2cjqA" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <br>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can add "text-center" Bootstrap class on your jumbotron to center it horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use flexbox for this. Apply some flex properties to the `.jumbotron` class and center align the items in `.centering`

```
.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centering {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6ngcws4/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
.centering{
    text-align: center!important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="span8 centering">
      <h1>Text 1</h1>
      <p>Text 2</p>
      <br>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JC82Il2cjqA" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <br>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```